# How to test method that uses Site.validatePassword(...)

Tags: apex, unit-test, customer-community, system-error

I'm writing tests for a custom Apex class regarding the self-registration of a customer community user.

One of the methods contains the API call to `Site.validatePassword(user, password, confirmPassword)`
and it seems the method can't be tested since it always throw an `System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error`
I tried running the test as normal user / system administator / guest user all with no success.

I found only this folks talking about the problem present since 2016 but with no solution:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MMZVIA4

Any idea on how to successfully test such a method? Here's an example:

```
/* method to be tested */
public static Id createUser(String username, String email, String nome, String cognome, String password, Id accountId) {
    User u = new User();      
    u.Username = username;
    u.Email = email;
    u.FirstName = nome;
    u.LastName = cognome;
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Rome';
    u.CommunityNickname = u.Username.left(40);

    //this will always fail in tests but works ok in production
    Site.validatePassword(u, password, password);

    Id res = Site.createExternalUser(
        u,
        accountId,
        password,
        true
    );

    return res;
}

/* test for the method*/
@IsTest
static void testCreateUser() {
    //retrieve a guest user present in the ORG
    User uRunning = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'guestUser' LIMIT 1];
    String username = 'm.rossi@example.com';
    String email = 'm.rossi@example.com';
    String nome = 'Mario';
    String cognome = 'Rossi';
    String password = 'P4ssw0rd10';

    Test.startTest();
    //runAs a guest user to simulate new anonymous user
    System.runAs(uRunning) { 
        //create a test account to correlate with new community user
        Account acc = TestUtils.creaAccount('Sample Account', uRunning);            
        TaCtrlLogin.createUser(username, email, nome, cognome, password, acc.Id);
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```